# Which one is reflexive, symmetric and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am doing an exercise where I need to find which one of the statements under are reflexive, symmetric and transitive. I will write what I think for each of the statements, could someone see if I am thinking right

Our domain is all real numbers:

a) x + y = 0
This one is reflexive only for (0,0) but not for all real numbers, it is symmetric for (0,0) but not for all real numbers, but I dont know how to see if it is symmetrical.

b) x = +- y
This is not reflexive for domain R, because (1,1) not true
I dont know how to see if its not symmetrical or not.

c) x = 2y
Not reflexive, (1,1) not true
to find symmetric do we do it like this? x = 2y -> x/2 = y  means not symmetric
dont know how to find transitive.

d) x*y >= 0
Not reflexive, (1,1) not treu
symmetric because x*y, y*x
transitive?

e) x*y = 0
same as d)

f) x = 1 or y = 1
Not sure what to do

Kinda long post, but would love to get some help. Thank you

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that the relation whose properties are being verified is (for example in (a)) $\{(x,y):x+y=0\}$? (Likewise for the others.)

Comment: Hey, yes that is what I mean, sorry for not making it more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) It's not reflexive but symmetric because addition is commutative: $x+y=0\iff y+x=0$. It's not transitive: for that it's enough to show up a specific counterexample, like $(2,-2)\in R,\ (-2,2)\in R$ while $(2,2)\notin R$ where $R$ denotes the relation defined in the exercise.

b) I think it's meant as $R=\{(x,y):x=y$ or $x=-y\}$. It's reflexive, symmetric and also transitive. To see these more directly we can restate $R=\{(x,y):|x|=|y|\}$.

c) It's not reflexive, not symmetric ($(1,2)\in R$ but $(2,1)\notin R$), and not even transitive: $(1,2),\ (2,4)\in R$ but $(1,4)\notin R$.

d) It's reflexive: for every real number $x$ we have $x\cdot x\ge 0$. It's also symmetric because multiplication is commutative, but it's not transitive: can you find three elements to witness this like above?

e) It's not reflexive: e.g. $(1,1)\notin R=\{(x,y):xy=0\}$ but symmetric, and also not transitive.

f) It's very similar to e) because $xy=0\iff x=0$ or $y=0$. Now $(1,1)$ happens to be in $R=\{(x,y):x=1$ or $y=1\}$ but no other $(x,x)$ pair, e.g. $(2,2)\notin R$.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

I'll just give some feedback on a) ... that should help you with the others as well:

> a) x + y = 0
> This one is reflexive only for (0,0) but not for all real numbers, it is symmetric for (0,0) but not for all real numbers, but I dont know how to see if it is symmetrical.

There is no such thing as 'being reflexive for (0,0) but not for others'.  If it holds for *all* (x,x), then it is reflexive, otherwise it is not reflexive. So this one is not reflexive

In general, to figure out whether some relation is symmetrical, ask yourself this:  Is it true that whenever you have $(x,y)$, you also have $(y,x)$?  So applied to a), that becomes: Is it true that whenever you have that $x+y=0$, you also have $y+x=0$?

For transitivity, the question is: is it true that whenever you have $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, that you then also have $(x,z)$? Applied to a): if $x+y=0$ and $y+z=0$, does that always mean that $x+z=0$?

Comment: Nice tips, how should i look at it when i want to see if it is transitive?

Comment: @ili Added that to my post

Answer (score 1):

In (a), the relation $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x+y=0\}$, is not reflexive because if $x \neq 0$ then $x+x \neq 0$.
It is symmetric because if $x+y=0$, then $y+x=0$.
It isn't transitive, because (for example) $(1,-1) \in S$, $(-1,1) \in S$, but $(1,1) \notin S$.

In (b), the relation is $T=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x = \pm y\}$.
It is reflexive because $x=x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.
If $x = \pm y$ then $y = \pm x$, whence it is symmetric.
Also, if $x = \pm y$ and $y = \pm z$ then $x = \pm z$, so it is transitive.

Now try to prove that in (c), $R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x=2y\}$ is not reflexive (aren't there numbers which are not the double of themselves?), not symmetric (aren't there numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x=2y$ but $y \neq 2x$), and not transitive (if $x=2y$ and $y=2z$ then $x=4z$; there are numbers $z$ for which $2z \neq 4z$, right?).

The relation in (d) is reflexive because $x^2 \geq 0$ for every $x$; symmetric because $xy=yx$, so if $xy\geq0$... It's not transitive: $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ are in the relation, but not $(1,-1)$.

In (e) it's not reflexive, symmetric and not transitive.

In (f) the relation is clearly not reflexive (think of $(0,0)$), it's symmetric but not transitive.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the definition of these 3 possible properties of relations on $\mathbb{R}$ again. The relation $x\sim y \iff x+y = 0 $ is indeed symmetric, since $x+y = 0 \iff y+x = 0$. I don't think this is the place to spoil all the answers, taking away from you the chance to think about it again.